# Once rigidbody collides script stops functioning unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity project in which an AI vehicle travels from transform to transform in a list of GameObjects.  The program works fine, until the rigidbody is collided with (both static colliders and other rigidbody/collider pairs).  After that, it just floats off until resistance stops it.  I suspect that it is due to the fact that the rigidbody is being used to move the object, but I had originally thought that this would simply negate the effects of a collision once the collision was over.  Additionally, the rotation towards the next waypoint also ceases when the rigidbody is hit.

My code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
  public List<GameObject> locations;
  public float RotationSpeed;
  public float moveSpeed = 1000f;
  private int ob = 0;
  private Quaternion _lookRotation;
  private Vector3 _direction;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      _direction = (locations[ob].transform.position - this.transform.position).normalized;
       _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

       this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);

       GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
  //     print(Vector3.Distance(locations[ob].transform.position, this.transform.position));
       if(Vector3.Distance(locations[ob].transform.position, this.transform.position) < 20f) {
    //     print("it got here");
         if(ob > locations.Count - 2) {
           ob = 0;
    //       print("true");
         } else {
           ob += 1;
      //     print("false");
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Do you see the issue, and if so, how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Edit: I had pasted an accidental character I typed in my program which broke it.  It has been removed since the issue was experienced previous to its addition and persisted after its removal.  Also, I do want the objects to bounce, but to continue to move afterwards.

Comment: There is a `+` at the end of your 2nd line in `Update()`, no idea how that compiled. However I can't see why this would cause the behavior you describe, do you have any Collision Events implemented in any other script?

Comment: That was a character I accidentally typed after I tested it (it didn't compile when I opened unity again).  Checking the game again this morning it still has the same issue.

Comment: It's likely this coide as such is unrelated to the problem.  It's really unclear what you are trying to do. is it a **physical game**, do you *want* the objects to bounce?  or, are you using the colliders strictly as triggers, as signals that you know where something is?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear, I do want the objects to bounce, but I want them to continue to attempt their course after a collision.  This is a very basic way to do it (point and go), but I don't see how I can fix this issue for a more complex system in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am awfully sorry for anyone with this problem, but after fiddling for a bit and duplicating my project everything works as expected.  I have no idea why it happened or how to fix it, but its fine now I guess...

Answer (score 0):

A simple tip: Never use GetComponent  () in Update, FixedUpdate, LateUpdate or While ... etc
Just create a global variable and call the reference in Start, or Awake.

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem though (and I know that I should make a variable, I was just throwing something together in a few minutes.)